# Regex split up parentheses group

Tags: java, regex

How can I split the following in Java:

```
(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
```

into:

```
1,2

3,4

5,6
```

I have tried:

```
test.split("(?<=\\()(.*)(?=\\))");
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be splitting on the `)`, `),(` or `)` (and then remove the null values manually, unless there's something for that I'm not aware of), if you want to split.

```
test.split("\\),\\(|\\)|\\(");
```

Although... matching might be simpler.

```
"\\(([^\\)]*)\\)"
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/IVTDRu)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to do it all in one line? Simple enough to break it down to pieces, like this for instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)";

    String[] firstSplit = test.split("\\),\\(");

    for (String token : firstSplit) {
        token = token.replaceAll("[\\(\\)]*", "");
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... I think this regex will work if you just use matching (versus a `split()` call):

```
/\([^\)]+\)/g
```

So in Java I think that would be...

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\([^\\)]+\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)");

while(m.find()) {
    java.lang.System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Minor notes: (1) you didn't create any group in your regex so you probably want to use `group()` instead of `group(1)`. (2) in Java ``\`` is `String`s metacharacter so if you want to create ``\`` literal you need to escape it by writing it as `"\\"`.

Answer (score 2):

In TextPad, which uses the Boost regex engine, this captures the numbers

```
(\b\d+,\d+\b)
```

and this captures the betweens:

```
((?:\),\()|(?:(?<!,)\()|(?:\)(?!,)))
```

Free-spaced:

```
(                   #Capture one of these three (quoted) things:
   (?:              
      \),\(         #    "),("      <--Must be the first option!
   )
|
   (?:
      (?<!,)\(      #    [not-a-comma]"("
   )
|
   (?:
      \)(?!,)       #    ")"[not-a-comma]
   )
)
```

Java program:

```
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;

/**
   <P><CODE>java NumCommaNumSplitXmpl</CODE></P>
 **/
public class NumCommaNumSplitXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      String sToSearch = "(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)";

      System.out.println("Capture numbers:");
         String sFindNumCommaNum = "(\\b\\d+,\\d+\\b)";

         Matcher m = Pattern.compile(sFindNumCommaNum).matcher(sToSearch);
         while(m.find())  {
            System.out.println(m.group());
         }

      System.out.println("Capture betweens:");
         String sFindBetweens = "((?:\\),\\()|(?:(?<!,)\\()|(?:\\)(?!,)))";

         m = Pattern.compile(sFindBetweens).matcher(sToSearch);
         while(m.find())  {
            System.out.println(m.group());
         }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\javastuff\]java NumCommaNumSplitXmpl
Capture numbers:
1,2
3,4
5,6
Capture betweens:
(
),(
),(
)
```

This was a fun problem.

Answer (score 1):

public class MainTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String msg = "(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)";
    String fmt = "(\\(|\\)\\,\\()|(\\(|\\))";

    String tokens[] = msg.split(fmt);
    for(String token: tokens) {
        System.out.println(token);
    }

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+,[0-9]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)");

    while(m.find()) {
        java.lang.System.out.println(m.group());
    }

}
```

}